# Need a awk/sed to replace the values present inside ${}

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, perl

I am trying to do url testing by fetching the values from env.properties file.

For example, my env.properties will look like this

```
a.host.name=wanx.com
b.host.name=xyu.com
c.host.name=${b.host.name}
d.host.name=${c.host.name}

url1=https://${d.host.name}/test
url2=https://${a.host.name}/test2
```

So far what I have done -
1. since there is a "." in the file I could not do the direct substitution. So I have replaced the dots with underscore using awk

```
awk -F= -vOFS="=" 'gsub(/\./,"_",$1)+1' endpoint_test.txt
```

Now my file looks like below -

```
a_host_name=wanx.com
b_host_name=xyu.com
c_host_name=${b.host.name}
d_host_name=${c.host.name}

url1=https://${d.host.name}/test
url2=https://${a.host.name}/test2
```

2. I am trying to replace the values present inside ${b.host.name} and ${c.host.name} , I have tried most of the awk commands found from google. 
   Below are the commands which I have tried

   `awk -F= -vOFS="${#*}" 'gsub(/\./,"_",$1)+1' endpoint_test2.txt`

   `awk -F\" '{OFS="\""; for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 2) gsub(/[$,]/,"",$i); gsub(/"/,""); print}' endpoint_test2.txt`

But it doesn't work. I want to change the dots to underscore present inside ${value}. So if I move that contents to a shell it's very easy for me to substitute.

Edit #1 -

Ultimately i need a output file like below -

```
a_host_name=wanx.com
b_host_name=xyu.com
c_host_name=${b.host.name}
d_host_name=${c.host.name}

url1=https://${d_host_name}/test
url2=https://${a_host_name}/test2
```

So if I convert this file to shell i will be doing this

```
a_host_name=wanx.com
b_host_name=xyu.com
c_host_name=${b_host_name}
d_host_name=${c_host_name}

url1=https://${d_host_name}/test
url2=https://${a_host_name}/test2

echo $url1
echo $url2
```

Output of this file -

```
https://xyu.com/test
https://wanx.com/test2
```

Edit #2 - 
I tried direct bash, But its saying as bad substitution since i need to replace the value inside ${}.

Edit #3 -

The OS i am trying is in AIX, And the file may not contain the same variable like  "a.host.name" as a  variable. It may also contains variable like "a.name.host" for example the file may looks like this -

```
a.b.host=qwel.wanx.net
b.host.name=ioy.xyu.net
c.xcv.host=poiu.deolite.net
d.host.name=${b.host.name}
e.host.name=${c.host.name}

abcv.stub.url=https://${d.host.name}/test
xcm.stub.url=https://${a.b.host}/test2
```

With this command i am able to achieve my edge case which i have mentioned in edit #3 -

```
perl -pe 's/^[\w.]+(?==)|\$\{[\w.]+\}/ $_ = $&; tr|.|_|; $_ /ge' file
```

Now my output looks like this -

```
a_b_host=qwel.wanx.net
b_host_name=ioy.xyu.net
c_xcv_host=poiu.deolite.net
d_host_name=${b_host_name}
e_host_name=${c_host_name}

abcv_stub_url=https://${d_host_name}/test
xcm_stub_url=https://${a_b_host}/test2
```

Finally i need the url alone in a separate file, Like below

```
https://ioy.xyu.net/test
https://qwel.wanx.net/test2
```

Comment: So you basically want to replace `.` by `_` in the variable names but not in the host names?

Comment: Yes @nohillside . That is what i want .

Comment: @ilkkachu - it works only when the variable is always same - for eg - "host.name". It wont work if the variable is 'a.name.host' or some different_variable = value

Comment: @ilkkachu - But the variable always ends with  '.host' - Your solution is close. I tried this sed - sed -e 's/\.*\.host/_*_host/g' filename - its just replacing the variable with '*'. I know its wrong . Now can you try modifying your answer and give ?

Comment: @HarishPC, actually, I rather like the Perl solution below. I wouldn't want to try the general solution in `sed` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
perl -pe 's/^[\w.]+(?==)|\$\{[\w.]+\}/$& =~ y|.|_|r/ge' < file
```

That is replace `.` with `_` on sequences of word characters or `.` that are at the beginning of the line and followed by `=` or inside `${...}`.

The `r` flag to the `y///` operator (so the result of the substitution is returned instead of being applied to the variable) needs perl 5.14 or above. With older versions, you can always do:

```
perl -pe 's/^[\w.]+(?==)|\$\{[\w.]+\}/$_ = $&; y|.|_|; $_/ge' < file
```

Now, for your ultimate task, it's just as easy to do the whole thing in `perl` here rather than interpret the code in a shell which would be quite dangerous:

```
 perl -lne '
    s/\$\{([\w.]+)\}/$v{$1}/g;
    if (/^([\w.]+)=(.*)/) {
      $v{$1} = $v = $2;
      print $v if $1 =~ /_url$/
    }' < file > separate-file
```

Comment: I am getting this error " Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "y|.|_|r"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "y|.|_|r "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors. - Did i miss anything ?

Comment: @HarishPC, old version of Perl? That indeed doesn't work with Perl 5.10.1. It seems to be the `/r` in `tr`. Wikipedia says that was added in 5.14, in 2011... `perl -pe 's/^[\w.]+(?==)|\$\{[\w.]+\}/ $_ = $&; tr|.|_|; $_ /ge'` seems to work as a workaround.

Comment: Its worked now. Thanks a lot for providing this answer. Can you please help me with the edit 3 in my question. I will mark your answer. Thanks again

Comment: @HarishPC, see edit.

Comment: In what sense is perl limited so it is requiring a `< file` instead of a simpler `file` ?

Comment: @isaac, it's not simpler. It's not even shorter if you omit the spaces around the `<`. See for instance [Why is \`sort < "$f1" \` preferred over \`sort -- "$f1"\`, and why is this preferred over \`sort "$f1"\`?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/458265) or [When should I use input redirection?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70756) and here for `perl` [Security implications of running perl -ne '...' \*](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
cat get_env_properties.sh 
sed -i'.bak' '
  :A
    s/\(.*\)\(\.\)\([^=]*=.*\)/\1_\3/
    tA
  :B
    s/\([^{]*{.*\)\(\.\)\([^}]*}.*\)/\1_\3/
    tB
' "$1"

. "$1"

echo "url1 = $url1"
echo "url2 = $url2"

mv "$1.bak" "$1"
```

You call it this way

```
./get_env_properties.sh env.properties
```

Your sed must be ok with -i

Comment: -E is not supported . Do you have any alternate solution ?

Comment: See my update answer, I remove the -E option not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed -e 's/\./_/g' -e '/com/ s/_/\./3g' test789
a_host_name=wanx.com
b_host_name=xyu.com
c_host_name=${b_host_name}
d_host_name=${c_host_name}

url1=https://${d_host_name}/test
url2=https://${a_host_name}/test2
```

- first sed will replace all `.` to `_`
- second sed will replace  3rd`_` to `.` if the line has `com`

Comment: @HarishPC try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer - This Sed ignoring first two lines variables. I am getting out like this a.host.name=qwel.wanx.net
b.host.name=ioy.xyu.net
c.host.name=poiu.deolite.net
d_host_name=${b_host_name}
e_host_name=${c_host_name}

abcv_stub_url=https://${d_host_name}/test
xcm_stub_url=https://${a_host_name}/test2

Comment: I tried this sed as well - sed -e 's/\./_/g' -e '/#net/ s/_/\./3g' endpoint_test3.txt , But it replacing both Value and variable. I am getting out like this - a_host_name=qwel_wanx_net
b_host_name=ioy_xyu_net
c_host_name=poiu_deolite_net
d_host_name=${b_host_name}
e_host_name=${c_host_name}

abcv_stub_url=https://${d_host_name}/test
xcm_stub_url=https://${a_host_name}/test2

Answer (score 0):

If what you call "output of this file" is your final desired result, try

```
    awk -F= '
                    {gsub (/[${}]/, "")
                    }
    !/^url/         {T[$1]=($2 in T)?T[$2]:$2
                     next
                    }
                    {sub (/^url[^=]*=/, "")
                     for (t in T)   if ($0 ~ t) sub (t, T[t])
                    }
    1
    ' file
https://xyu.com/test
https://wanx.com/test2
```